# Return false, not cancelling for each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop

I am using a function, showVisible(), to gather all the marker ID's from a googlemap, pass them to an array, and then call the corresponding object data from the server using AJAX.

This is triggered whenever someone click a marker cluster on the map. I need to stop loop cycling through the array if someone clicks on a marker before all the ajax calls have been made.

I have tried to use an if statement so that if breakAjax is "true" then the loop should return false. Even though I can see on the console that the the variable shifts to true, it isn't triggering the break.

The full code for the function is below:

```
function showVisible() {
  visRunning = true
  console.log('show visible')

  $('#objects_list').empty()

  function unique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
      if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
  }

  scoots = unique(locStr)
  totalScoots = scoots.length
    //console.log('total scoots ' + totalScoots);
  var scootOutput = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < scoots.length; i++) {
    if (scootOutput === 0) {
      $('#objects_list').empty()
    }
    console.log('breakAjax: ' + breakAjax)

    countManager()


    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://scootapi.stuffstory.com/api/stuff/' + scoots[i],
      dataType: 'json',
      type: "get",
      success: function(stuffData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        $('#objects_list').append('<a class="stuff_wrapper" target="_blank" onclick="ga("send", "event", "grid view scooter ' + stuffData.id + '", "click", "frontPage")" href="../scooter/?view=' + stuffData.id + '"><div class="stuff_holder" style="background-image:url(' + stuffData.image + '/convert?w=250&h=250);"><div class="scooter_title_sm"><div class="title_wrapper"><div class="scooter_title_1 cursive_sm">' + stuffData.make + '</div><div class="scooter_title_2 lato_sm">' + stuffData.model + '</div><div class="scooter_title_3 cursive_sm">' + stuffData.year + '</div></div></div></div></a>')
        console.log('breakAjax: ' + breakAjax)
        stuffSizer()
        scootOutput++
        if (scootOutput === totalScoots) {
          visRunning = false
        }
      },
      error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}
    })

    if (breakAjax === "true") {
      return false;
    }

  };
}
```

Comment: Is `breakAjax` a boolean? If so, should `if (breakAjax === "true")` be `if (breakAjax === true)`?

Comment: Oops. It was originally, and then I changed it just to test before I posted in on here. I'll change it back, but it didn't appear to make any difference.

Comment: I don't see any code that ever assigns a value to breakAjax, so how can it ever be true or "true"?

Comment: Also to cancel a loop, to break out of it, you should use, break;. If using for  example a jQuery foreach, you should use, return false;.

Comment: Quentin - there is a map-cluster click handler that assigns the value, elsewhere in the page. 

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'click', function(c) {
     if (visRunning === true){
     breakAjax = "true"
     }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `breakAjax` does not change inside the loop.

JavaScript is single threaded.

Code that isn't inside the loop cannot change the value of that variable while the loop is running (which happens practically instantaneously anyway).

---

You seem to have forgotten that the A in Ajax stands for asynchronous.

You are going over the loop, making *n* HTTP requests and setting up *n* event handlers (the success function) that will run when the *got HTTP response* event fires.

If you want to stop the success function from doing anything with the data, then you need to test `breakAjax` inside the success function.

It is far too late, at that point, to stop the HTTP request being sent. If that is the goal, then you'll need to refactor your logic (probably using recursive functions) so that your loop is incremented by the `success` handler instead of using `for`.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thank you